# Select promoted items grouped by another attribute

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

From table like below:

```
id | node_id | promoted | group_type | created_at         |status
------------------------------------------------------------------
8  |   4321  |    1     |     3      | 2018-01-08 13:29:55|   1 
4  |   4321  |    0     |     3      | 2018-01-06 11:22:53|   1 
3  |   4321  |    0     |     1      | 2018-01-05 23:19:02|   1 
2  |   4321  |    1     |     1      | 2018-01-05 21:20:15|   1 
1  |   4321  |    1     |     3      | 2018-01-05 11:09:51|   1
```

I have to get one `id` and `group_type` values per each `group_type`.

If there is promoted item in the group, query should return it's `id` and `group_type`.

If there are more than one promoted items in the group, most recent promoted record should be returned.

If there is no promoted item in the group, query should return most recent record.

Using query below I managed to get almost what I need

```
SELECT a.id, a.group_type, a.promoted, a.created_at
 FROM ( 
       SELECT group_type, MAX(promoted) AS max_promoted
              FROM nodes
              WHERE node_id=4321 AND status=1
              GROUP BY group_type
      ) AS g
 INNER JOIN nodes AS a
 ON a.group_type = g.group_type AND a.promoted = g.max_promoted
 WHERE node_id= 4321 AND status=1 ORDER BY created_at
```

Unfortunately when there is more than one promoted item in the group I get both.

Any idea how to get only one promoted item per group?

**EDIT:**
If there is more than one group, query should return multiple rows but **one per every group**.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the result of the query by adding `LIMIT 0,1` at the end of the query.

As you have ordered your result it will works.

For more information about LIMIT see : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/limit-optimization.html

Comment: This will limit to only one item total. I need one item per group not in total. So in response I should get more than one row. In example table are 2 two group types, group_type: 1, and group_type: 3. In this case query result should have 2 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Edited: You should order items in `descending` to get the latest one on top and `limit` items as per required i.e. 1 or 2 and so on. Also `union` will help in getting latest result either promoted in case not promoted. The last `limit` will result only single (required) row. Here's your query:

```
(SELECT a.id, a.group_type, a.promoted, a.created_at
 FROM ( 
       SELECT group_type, MAX(promoted) AS max_promoted
              FROM nodes
              WHERE node_id=4321 and status=1
              GROUP BY group_type
      ) AS g
 INNER JOIN nodes AS a
 ON a.group_type = g.group_type AND a.promoted = g.max_promoted
 WHERE node_id= 4321 and status=1 ORDER BY created_at desc
limit 1)
union
(select a.id, a.group_type, a.promoted, a.created_at from nodes a order by created_at desc limit 1)
limit 1
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This will return only one item, not one pre group